# Angular 1.4.7 how to return an <a> element from a filter - what is the best way

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-filters

I'm finding this to be very hard to determine the 'best' way as well as a 'simple' way to approach this.

We are sending a json object that is an array that looks like so:

```js
rows = [ "test.com", 'items2', 3000, '2020010203') ]

<td ng-repeat="row in rows track by $index">
  {{ field | filterRowField }}
</td>
```

Currently all the filter is doing is checking if the object is a date or not and returning a moment JS element if it is.

```
angular.module('mymodule').filter 'filterRowField', ->
  (field) ->
    if moment(field, moment.ISO_8601).isValid()
      field = moment(field).format("MM-DD-YYYY h:mm a")

    field
```

I need to return an ng-ref element if it matches a uri regex, or do it with an switch-when statement. Anyone more familiar with this have any advice on which method would be best to use?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like a good use case for a directive

Comment: That is what I was thinking but as I don't have a lot of angularJS 1.4.7 experience it didn't sound as fun

Comment: Ideally I wanted to just return a new <a> element with the href on it. Other than that not being the 'ideal' solution do you see any problems with that approach

Comment: You can't output html in `{{}}` ... only text. So your idea of returning from the filter wouldn't work with the interpolation braces

Comment: What about some cleverly crafted regex to hide / show also with ng-if

Comment: You could use `nf-if` ... if table is large would be expensive though